# Weird delete on merge in Subversion

Tags: svn, merge

I have a subversion repository with trunk and a branch. Now when I try to merge trunk into my branch (no matter if I use TortoiseSVN or commandline svn), a directory and an included file become marked for deletion. But in the merge log there is no incoming delete for this file.

If I run `svn status` now, it shows me something like

```
D  +  path/to/directory
D  +  path/to/directory/file
```

**Edit:** As Álvaro G. Vicario pointed out, the `+` indicates "history scheduled with commit" -- what would that mean in my situation?

Now I am scared, that (because I only discovered this by accident) I might have had data loss on a similar merge in the past without noticing. Can anyone give me a hint on what might have happened here?

Comment: The concept of renaming does not really exist in Subversion. You have to copy the file and remove the original (although there is a `svn rename` subcommand that will do both things for you).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But does not `svn info` usually indicate those cases where an actual rename action has been detected with a `+` next to the respective delete and add?

Comment: Nope, `+` means [History scheduled with commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html)

Comment: Okay, and what would this mean in my situation?

Comment: It's hard to say because we don't know your code base and what's supposed to change or not. An scheduled deletion means that something has been deleted *or* renamed: you can tell out by seeing whether there is an equivalent addition. I'll try to provide a more positive answer.

Comment: I know and I'm sorry that I am being vague. But first of all it's hard to tell what the equivalent addition is (because there's an awful lot of them). Second, the core of the question is not about the `+` but about the delete being there in the first place as there is no incoming delete for the file in the merge.

Answer (score 1):

If unsure, I recommend that you start again and do everything from TortoiseSVN. Assuming that you didn't commit the merge yet, find your *branch* working copy and:

1. Right click on your working copy root and **Revert**.
2. Right click on your working copy root and **Check for modifications**. Remove unversioned items if any.
3. Right click... and **Merge**. Pick "Merge a range of revisions" and **Next**. Pick the trunk at "URL to merge from". Hit *Show log* and highlight all the revisions you want to merge. The bottom panel will display changed items. When happy, click **OK** and proceed with the merge.
4. Right click... and **Check for modifications** to inspect what will be committed. Pay special attention to the "Copied from URL" column. (Right click on column headers to show/hide columns.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not commit the merge yet and I already checked out a completely new working copy of my branch. What I did not try yet is explicitly choosing revisions to merge. I also did not try the "copied from URL" column. I will give that a try. Still, any other ideas apart from "unclean working copy" (I'd rule that one out)?